# runtests works in matlab 2015b but not in 2013b

Tags: matlab, testing

I tryed the runtests function example at http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/runtests.html
and in matlab 2015b everthing works perfectly. But in matlab 2013b I get the following error

```
>> runtests
Error using runtests (line 41)
Not enough input arguments.
```

And if I explizietly one of the m-files

```
>> runtests('typeTest.m')
```

I get

```
Error using matlab.unittest.TestSuite.fromFile (line 94)
"C:\Users\u16h62\Documents\MATLAB\Example\typeTest.m" is not a valid test    file.
 Error in runtests>createSuite (line 60)
 suite = TestSuite.fromFile(file);
 Error in runtests>@(test)createSuite(test,parser.Results.Recursively) (line   41)
suites = cellfun(@(test)createSuite(test, parser.Results.Recursively), ...
Error in runtests (line 41)
suites = cellfun(@(test)createSuite(test, parser.Results.Recursively), ...
```

Can someone say me what I am doing wrong, please?

Answer (score 1):

The runtests function changed between these releases. It looks like the 0-input syntax was first documented for this function in R2014b.

See the R2013b version of the runtests documentation to determine how the function works in that release:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2013b/matlab/ref/runtests.html

Also, check the release notes to read about changes that were made to the function:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html